# How to increase startup speed of GUI when creating .exe?

Tags: python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I am looking to increase the startup speed of my GUI program that I made. It imports several different modules. It starts up fast in PyCharm (roughly 3-4 seconds) but when I convert it to .exe using PyInstaller it takes up to 10 seconds before it starts up.

I understand that it takes a while to load because its working on loading all of the dependencies of the program.

I am using the --onedir option for PyInstaller.

Is there any other way to increase my startup time? I have seen other similar posts but none really answer the question or give other alternatives to use.

Comment: Do your app runs faster when executing your script directly using Python?

Comment: Yes, it takes around 3-4 seconds to run. In Pyinstaller I made a console window to see what was going on, for the first 8 seconds it just shows a blank console, I assume it would be trying to grab the files to run the .exe

Comment: Which library are you using for the GUI? Try using `--one-file` with `--noupx` when building your app.

Comment: I am using PyQt5, i'll test that out and see

Comment: @M.R. I ran with the above, the console window shows blank for about 15-19seconds then shows a matplotlibdepcractionwarning message, then finally starts up program. --onefile option is a lot slower, so that is why I use the --onedir option

Comment: Are you using matplot lib with your app?

Comment: @M.R. Yes, I have to create graphs, I don't know if that warning would cause anything because the console window is initially blank for a majority of the time

Comment: Try to use `virtualenv` then build your app on there. It would remove unnecessary dependencies from your output.
Also put a `print` in the first line of your code and see if it executes faster?

Comment: @M.R. Is there a good tutorial on how to do that?

Comment: Just use (this)[https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html] then install your packages and recreate the executable int the env.

Comment: @M.R. I created the virtualenv, instead of installing the packages one by one, can I copy from the site-packages folder in python? Or am I mis-understanding it? Also, when you create the exe should it be --onefile or --onedir?

Comment: No, you should install packages, as usual, you can create a text file, put your package names on each line and use `pip install -r <yourtxt>.txt` to install them automatically. Just use the faster way `one-dir`.

Comment: @M.R. Do I also need to install pyinstaller again as well?

Comment: The code started faster but it hangs after the matplotlib warning. ----->

Code started
c:\users\drees\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:627: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)

Comment: Have you installed the same version matplot lib?

Comment: Yes, I am using current version 3.1. I put a print statement at end of each module to see how long they are taking and it seems that it hangs on the matplotlib warning for about 2-4 seconds after some modules have loaded, then the rest of my modules continue to load which takes another few seconds. In pycharm it takes 2.49 seconds but after using pyinstaller it goes to 8.22 seconds to open program